# AngularJs $watch Why isn't this working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get values to update in reverse in this AngularJs script i'm writing here:
http://jsfiddle.net/flashpunk/tR5Mr/1/

```
$scope.$watch('watchList', function(newV,oldV) {
    console.log('change');
    $scope.main.right.assets = addAssets();
    $scope.main.right.roa = roaCalc();
    $scope.main.right.target = targetCalc();
}, true);
```

You can see that you can change the values in the Slide1, Slide2, Slide3, Slide4, and Slide5 input boxes which effect the MAIN input boxes, however the watch function doesn't seem modify the Slide boxes when the MAIN boxes are modified.

Can anyone help me make this work? Ive been racking my brains for hours on this.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "in reverse"?

Comment: @KayakDave added more info to the OP - sorry i wasn't clear initially. What I meant was the Slide 1-5 values modify the Main values, but the main values don't modify the Slide 1-5 values.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $scope.watchList;
}, function (newV, oldV) {
    console.log('change');
    $scope.main.right.assets = addAssets();
    $scope.main.right.roa = roaCalc();
    $scope.main.right.target = targetCalc();
}, true);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tR5Mr/3/)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but this seems to work the same way as my original code does. I've expanded more on what I meant by "reverse" in the OP.

Comment: @flashpunk, Even it has racked my brains also. As aet has pointed out main value is getting recalculated based on the values of other textboxes  thus it seems values are not getting modified. Also you are not modifying `slider` value in any method

Comment: thanks, at least I know i'm not the only one going crazy. I dont understand why changing the main slider values would trigger the watch event (why i have the console.log in there).

Comment: @flashpunk, I don't know about you but I definitely need a peg of beer after this

Comment: If you have any insight how I can do this without writing 40 different functions to calculate the math, i will certainly be glad to buy you a bunch of beers!

Answer (score 0):

Your watch is working.  It's being triggered by changes to any of the boxes.

The issue is your watch only computes values for your main boxes when triggered.  You need to detect what values changed (slide or main) and calculate in the appropriate direction based on which changed..

The easiest solution may be two watches- the one you currently have stays watching all the slide boxes. So that watchlist will now look like:

```
$scope.watchList = [
    $scope.slide1,
    $scope.slide2,
    $scope.slide3,
    $scope.slide4,
    $scope.slide5   
];
```

And a new watch which watches the main and updates the slide boxes.

```
$scope.$watch('main', function(newV,oldV) {
    console.log('main changed');
    //Update any slide values that need updating here
}, true);
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Is it possible to do without having to make a calculation for each of the possible changes?

Comment: Yeah, currently you cannot even really modify the MAIN values, as it immediately recalculates based on what is in the other boxes.

Comment: If you need the calculation in order to update the box, then you're kind of stuck doing it.